# Polyfill basics: How to implement a polyfill for Uint8Array.fill

Tags: javascript, arrays, polyfills

Polyfill newbie here. I'm completely baffled by this simple case, in which I want to initialize a typed array:

```
var x = new Uint8Array(3).fill(42);
console.log(x);
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox: the console shows `[42, 42, 42]`. Safari, which does not support the `fill` method, throws this error: `"TypeError: new Uint8Array(3).fill is not a function."`. This makes perfect sense. So I figure I need to implement a polyfill, right? Right! MDN offers [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill), but when I add this chunk of code nothing changes: Safari continues to throw the same error. Obviously I'm doing something wrong. And is this even this the right polyfill to use for `Uint8Array`?

Here's the code I'm executing (including the MDN polyfill):

```
if (!Array.prototype.fill) {
     Array.prototype.fill = function(value) {

    // Steps 1-2.
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
    }

    var O = Object(this);

    // Steps 3-5.
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // Steps 6-7.
    var start = arguments[1];
    var relativeStart = start >> 0;

    // Step 8.
    var k = relativeStart < 0 ?
      Math.max(len + relativeStart, 0) :
      Math.min(relativeStart, len);

    // Steps 9-10.
    var end = arguments[2];
    var relativeEnd = end === undefined ?
      len : end >> 0;

    // Step 11.
    var final = relativeEnd < 0 ?
      Math.max(len + relativeEnd, 0) :
      Math.min(relativeEnd, len);

    // Step 12.
    while (k < final) {
      O[k] = value;
      k++;
    }

    // Step 13.
   return O;
   };
}


var x = new Uint8Array(3).fill(42);
console.log(x);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: because it's a `Uint8Array` not an `Array`? have you tried changing the polyfill code to `if (!Uint8Array.prototype.fill) { Uint8Array.prototype.fill = function(value){...`?

Comment: @Rhumborl: Yes -- that did the trick. Thank you! (Now why didn't I see that? Sometimes it's the most obvious things that are the hardest to see...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Just repeating @Rhumbori's comment, to close out my question...)

Change these lines

```
if (!Array.prototype.fill) {
 Array.prototype.fill = function(value) {
```

to

```
if (!Uint8Array.prototype.fill) {
 Uint8Array.prototype.fill = function(value) {
```